# How can i match regex without spaces in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this regex and its working fine

```
var r = new RegExp(page, 'i'); 
$("ul.nav-tabs a").filter(function(){ return $(this).text().match(r) }).parent().addClass("active");
```

But it don't work if i have

`page = useraccount`

and text is `User Account`

Is there any way to have general regex which matches normal words plus joined words

Comment: try `$(this).text().replace(' ', '').match(r)`

Comment: Better like this `$(this).text().replace(/\s/g, "").match(r)` which will get rid of all white space characters

Comment: page is the variable i mean the words which i want to match like useraccount

Comment: @devnull69 , that worked but i have noew one more problem that also matches two links `user` and `useraccount` , is there any way out

Comment: `page = "^"+page+"$";`

Comment: @dualed that didn't work

Comment: If you want to match only "user" with `page=="user"` and not `useraccount` you'll have to show us more from `$(this).text()`. What values can it have?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it is not going to work, because 'user' is always inside of 'useraccount'.

You can either make it work for your specific use case by working around some issues, or you can do it the right way.

I suggest adding another field to the links which you can match exactly. Or, even cleaner, to the `<li>`. Like this:

```
<ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li data-page="user"><a href="..." >User</a></li>
    <li data-page="useraccount"><a href="..." >User Accounts</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Then you can just do this in your javascript:

```
var elements = $("ul.nav-tabs > li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('page') == page;
});
elements.addClass("active");
```

Comment: btw. You probably want to replace `class="nav-tabs"` with an `id` because it looks like it's going to be unique on your site.